# sum(coalesce()) returns 1 less then true value

Tags: sql, sqlplus

I have a table that has 2 columns that keep home and away team id's then 2 columns that keep home and away points, I want to query the database so that it returns the total of points a specific team has earned. Here is my code and it returns a answer that is 1 less then the actual value and it does that for each team I try, why would this be?

```
select sum(coalesce(hpoints,apoints)) Points
from plays_a
where (tawayid='2013T1' or thomeid='2013T1')
```

Thank you

Will try this other query.

Edit-
Didn't seem to work it returned 5 for this data.

```
HPOINTS    THOMEID    APOINTS    TAWAYID
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       1.5 2013T5            2.5 2013T6
         3 2013T4              1 2013T1
         2 2013T6              2 2013T3
         2 2013T2              2 2013T5
         3 2013T6              1 2013T1
         3 2013T2              1 2013T3
       2.5 2013T4            1.5 2013T5
         1 2013T3              3 2013T1
         1 2013T4              3 2013T2
         3 2013T6              1 2013T5
         3 2013T3              1 2013T2
```

NEVERMIND looks like it was correct will try again with a different team and post back

Comment: Include (minimal) sample data which results in the off-by-one behavior. The database is correct - this makes the query in relation to *the data* suspect.

Comment: As I say in my answer, the issue with your current query is that it's always going to use the home team's points score, even if `2013T1` were the away team. I'd suggest you read up on `COALESCE` to understand why (and the differences will be when it happens that the total of home points scored are different from the total of away points scored, when 2013T1 were the away team)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this query:

```
select sum(CASE WHEN thomeid='2013T1' THEN hpoints ELSE apoints END) Points
from plays_a
where (tawayid='2013T1' or thomeid='2013T1')
```

In your original query, you're always taking the home teams points score, if it's not `NULL`, even if the team was the away team. That doesn't seem correct. Of course, your table might be completely bizarre and always only filling in the away columns **or** the home columns in any particular row, but that's not how I'd expect the data to look and doesn't seem to match your description.